# No changes in schema detected

Tags: python, enums, sqlalchemy, alembic

**Environment:**
alembic==0.8.4
SQLAlchemy==1.0.10
Flask==0.10.1
flask-marshmallow==0.6.2
Flask-Migrate==1.6.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.4
flask-restful-swagger==0.19
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-SSLify==0.1.5

**DB Model Original with migrate file**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import INTEGER
import enum
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import ENUM
from mapping_service.app import db


class MappingStatusEnum(enum.Enum):
    OVERRIDDEN = 'overridden'
    SUGGESTION = 'suggestion'


    @staticmethod
    def list():
        return list(map(lambda status: status.value, MappingStatusEnum))

class MappingStatus(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "MappingStatus"
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset': 'utf8'}

    id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True),
                primary_key=True,
                autoincrement=True,
                nullable=False)
    status = Column(ENUM(*MappingStatusEnum.list()), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

**DB Model changed but Schema change not detected**

```
 class MappingStatusEnum(enum.Enum):
        OVERRIDDEN = 'overridden'
        SUGGESTION = 'suggestion'
        REJECTED = 'rejected'
        FAILED = 'failed'
```

As you can see I have changed the statuses possible and added two new ones. When executing

```
python manange.py db migrate
```

All I get is the following message:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected.
```

What can I do so that alembic can see the schema change and create the appropriate migrate file? I am not very Flask, SQLAlchemy savvy, so I might be doing something extremely stupid that I just can't figure out.

Comment: Facing same issue, did you find any solution ?